# Import errors when compiling contracts using truffle

Tags: solidity

**Please help me understand this error**

```
`**enter code here**`No build configuration found. Preparing to compile contracts.

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
Error: Could not find 
import  from any sources; imported from /home/a/Documents/sos/contracts/crowdsale.sol
    at Resolver.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/resolver/dist/lib/resolver.js:53:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/resolver/dist/lib/resolver.js:5:42)
    at <anonymous>
Truffle v5.1.28 (core: 5.1.28)
Node v8.10.0
```

This is the error I get when I compile my contracts. this is the start of my crontracts.sol

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;
import "../../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
import "../../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol";
import "../../node_modules/openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/validation/PausableCrowdsale.sol"
import "./token.sol"
```

npm installed openzeppelin modules as 0.6.0 sol and the truffle version is using 0.5.16 solc

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using .. in path specific as state in the note of this section: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.10/layout-of-source-files.html#paths.

So what can you do instead? Just like in the note i show above you should use global map and then setup remapping to it they explain it here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.10/layout-of-source-files.html#use-in-actual-compilers.

But since you are using truffle i recommend an easy approach which is just copy the folder you need into contract folder and then import it like in this case you should copy crowdsale folder to contract folder in your project and change the import to this:

`import "./crowdsale/CrowdSale.sol"`

Which is much more readable instead of using ../